# horizontal listview with only text

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

i have a little problem. I need do a simple Horizontal ListView, no more. My code works perfectly but the listview is vertical. Its only text in the listView.. Android Studio 2.3.3

Like this::: https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Dz52ZwzwOvo/WDRBi4kDwoI/AAAAAAAActE/nhsM7pBvcXI75-Epz16b3jyEQwk27J-XgCLcB/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/UWPHorizontalListViewExample.png

My code

```
String[] itemsListaGeneros = new String[] { "piza1", "piza2", "piza3", "piza4", "piza4", "piza5" };   //// LISTA ITEMS A MOSTRAR ////


    // Define a new Adapter  // First parameter - Context  // Second parameter - CUSTOM TEXT EN XML customlistviewgeneros  // Third parameter - the Array of data
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.customlistviewgeneros, itemsListaGeneros);
    listViewGeneros.setAdapter(adapter); /// SETEO ADAPTADOR PARA LISTVIEW --- ADAPTER ///


    // ListView Item Click Listener
    listViewGeneros.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition  = position;

            // ListView Clicked item value
            String  itemValue = (String) listViewGeneros.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Show Alert
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using RecyclerViews doing this:

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```